# Using awk and/or grep for two columns from one file1 and grep column 2 value from file2 while inserting column1 from file 1 before column 1 in file2

Tags: linux, awk, grep

Good day.

I have two files, vmList and flavorList, the vmList containing the following:

```
$ cat /tmp/vmList
cf0012vm001| OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at                                 | -
cf0012vm001| accessIPv4                                               |
cf0012vm001| accessIPv6                                               |
cf0012vm001| cf0012v_internal_network network                  | 192.168.210.10
cf0012vm001| created                                                  | 2021-09-17T17:21:39Z
cf0012vm001| flavor                                                   | nd.c8r16d50e60 (89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1)
cf0012vm001| hostId                                                   | fcf39100bcc6ae57a8212f97d3251ac43913719f2aebcaa72006956e
cf0012vm001| key_name                                                 | -

cf0012vm002| OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at                                 | -
cf0012vm002| accessIPv4                                               |
cf0012vm002| accessIPv6                                               |
cf0012vm002| cf0012v_internal_network network                  | 192.168.210.11
cf0012vm002| created                                                  | 2021-09-17T17:21:37Z
cf0012vm002| flavor                                                   | nd.c8r16d50e60 (89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1)
cf0012vm002| hostId                                                   | e1590af8ddd57f1e2e74617d6c3631195e410bdd188a0b59813ffbef
cf0012vm002| id                                                       | 0e292900-6b50-4055-9842-d95e54fa1490
```

and the flavorList containing the following information:

```
$ cat /tmp/flavorList
+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------+------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| ID                                   | Name             | Memory_MB | Disk | Ephemeral | Swap  | VCPUs | RXTX_Factor | Is_Public |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------+------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| 711f0ff2f01d403689819b6cbab36e42     | nd.c4r8d21s8e21  | 8192      | 21   | 21        | 8192  | 4     |             | N/A       |
| 78a70b62efae4fbcb35994aeb0f87678     | nd.c8r16d31s8e31 | 16384     | 31   | 31        | 8192  | 8     |             | N/A       |
| 78f4fe71cc3340a59c62fc0b32d81e3f     | nd.c4r16d100     | 16384     | 100  | 0         |       | 4     |             | N/A       |
| 7a7e6ae4bfe34ac4ab3983b8f764a8ce     | nd.c2r8d40       | 8192      | 40   | 0         |       | 2     |             | N/A       |
| 832169fed2244bb6b1739ab3db0f232e     | nd.c1r4d100      | 4096      | 100  | 0         |       | 1     |             | N/A       |
| 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
| 8e968623e5c44674b33e1cc1f892e32d     | nd.c9r40d50      | 40960     | 50   | 0         |       | 9     |             | N/A       |
| 8e96a7044566406f9ef7eba48c2a8c55     | nd.c5r4d81       | 4096      | 81   | 0         |       | 5     |             | N/A       |
| 8fd07e2004f84658a76af1cd8b9cea43     | nd.c2r8d50       | 8192      | 50   | 0         |       | 2     |             | N/A       |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------+------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
```

My goal is to find the 'flavor' in the vmList, then grep the flavor value (nd.c8r16d50e60) from the flavorList, which in itself works:

```
$ for f in `grep flavor /tmp/vmList|awk '{print $4}'`;do grep ${f} /tmp/flavorList;done
| 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
| 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
```

However, I would like to add the first parameter from the vmList (cf0012vm001 and cf0012vm002) to precede the output, either in a line above the output or in front of the line:

```
cf0012vm001 | 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
cf0012vm002 | 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
```

or even:

```
cf0012vm001
| 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |

cf0012vm002
| 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
```

Please advise.

Bjoern

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- a `flavor` does not contain spaces
- a specific ordering of the output has not be stated
- `vmList`: column/field #1 could be associated with different `flavor`s [**NOTE:** not supported by sample data set; OP would need to refute/confirm]

One `GNU awk` idea that uses an array of arrays:

```
awk -F'|' '                                  # input field delimiter = "|" for both files
FNR==NR {                                    # for 1st file ...
          name=gensub(/ /,"","g",$2)         # remove all spaces from field #2 and save in awk variable "name"
          if (name == "flavor") {            # if field #2 == "flavor" ...
             split($3,arr,"(")               # split field #3 using "(" as delimiter, storing results in array arr[]
             gsub(" ","",arr[1])             # remove all spaces from first array entry
             flavors[arr[1]]                 # keep track of unique flavors
             col1[arr[1]][$1]                # keep track of associated values from column/field #1
          }
          next
        }
FNR>3   {                                    # for 2nd file, after ignoring first 3 lines ...
          if (NF == 1) next                  # skip line if it only has 1 "|" delimited field
          name=gensub(/ /,"","g",$3)         # remove all spaces from field #3 and save in awk variable "name"
          if (name in flavors)               # if name is in our list of flavors ...
             for (i in col1[name])           # loop through list of columns (from 1st file)
                 print i,$0                  # print column (from 1st file) plus current line
        }
' vmList flavorList
```

This generates:

```
cf0012vm001 | 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
cf0012vm002 | 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
```

**NOTE:** while this output appears to be sorted by the first column this is merely a coincidence; if a specific order needs to be guaranteed this can likely be done by adding an appropriate `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` entry; OP just needs to state the desired ordering

Comment: Thank you Mark.


When I tried your solution, I got syntax errors on lines 7 and 15:

```
awk: cmd. line:7:              col1[arr[1]][$1]
awk: cmd. line:7:                          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:15:              for (i in col1[name])
awk: cmd. line:15:                            ^ syntax error
```
To confirm, 'flavors' do not contain spaces, the order depends on the vmList, and lastly, the flavors differ depending on the VM type in the vmList.

Bjoern

Comment: @BjoernHehmann hmmm ... the 2 line numbers mentioned in your error messages refer to the multi-dimensional arrays, which require`GNU awk`; I'm thinking you aren't working with `GNU awk` ... what is the output from running `awk --version` in your environment?  assuming you're not able to install `GNU awk` in your environment ... I can look at rewriting my answer or you could try tshiono's answer (though that solution may need work if a value in the 1st column (from `vmList`) can be listed more than once with different `flavor` values)

Comment: awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: ah, that's it; according to this [GNU awk feature history](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html), `arrays of arrays` became available in `version 4.0`; I think (don't quote me on this) `version 4.0` came out in ~2011; you may want to see if you can get a newer version installed (eg, I've got `version 5.x` on my systems); might also want to check your versions of `bash`, `sed`, `sort`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
echo "VM Name     | ID                                   | Flavor Name      | Memory_MB | Disk | Ephemeral | Swap  | VCPUs | RXTX_Factor | Is_Public |"
echo "------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------+------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+"

awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' '
NR==FNR && $2=="flavor" {sub(/[[:blank:]].+/, "", $3); a[$1]=$3; next}
{
    for (i in a) {
       if (a[i] == $3) print i " " $0
    }
}
' /tmp/vmList /tmp/flavorList | sort -k1.9,1.11n
```

Output:

```
VM Name     | ID                                   | Flavor Name      | Memory_MB | Disk | Ephemeral | Swap  | VCPUs | RXTX_Factor | Is_Public |
------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------+------+-----------+-------+-------+-------------+-----------+
cf0012vm001 | 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
cf0012vm002 | 89ba4c986a28447aa27de65bca986db1     | nd.c8r16d50e60   | 16384     | 50   | 60        |       | 8     |             | N/A       |
```

- The field separator `[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*` splits the record
  on the pipe character with preceding / following blank characters if any.
- The condition `NR==FNR && $2=="flavor"` matches the `flavor` line
  in `vmList`.
- The statement `sub(/[[:blank:]].+/, "", $3)` extracts the `nd.xxx`
  field by removing the substring after the blank character.
- `a[$1]=$3` stores the `nd.xxx` field keyed by the 1st `cfxxx` field.
- The final `for (i in a)` loop prints the matched lines in `flavorList` with prepending the `cfxxx` field.
- `sort -k1.9,1.11n` sorts the output by the substring from the 1st field 9th character to the 1st field 11th character. The trailing `n` option specifies the numerical sort.

Comment: Thank you tshiono.  This one works like a charm.
One more question, where would you place the header, ie:

BEGIN {print "VM Name| Flavor Name|Memory_MB | Disk | Ephemeral | Swap  | VCPUs | RXTX_Factor | Is_Public"}

Comment: @Bjoern yes, you'd want to print the header in the `BEGIN {...}` block; keep in mind this will always print the header even if you don't find any matches between the 2x files

Comment: Also want to add that the output should be in numerical order based on the last 3 digits of the first column in the vmList (I have one such vmList with 73 lines).

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you for answering the OP's question for me! I've updated my answer accordingly
but putting the header lines out of the `awk` script using `echo` just to avoid to be `sort`ed.
Needless to say it would be more elegant to enclose them in the `BEGIN` block.

Comment: As `awk` does not have the built-in `sort` function, it will be easier to use `sort` command to sort
the output by the last 3 digits of the first field. I've updated my answer adding the `sort` command.
It assumes the string length of `vmList` field is fixed. If not, please let me know.